# Why is this data being flipped

Tags: c++, endianness, memcpy

Below is an example of processing very similar to what I am working with.  I understand the concept of endianness and have read through the suggested posts but it doesn't seem to explain what is happening here.

I have an array of unsigned characters that I am packing with data.  I was under the impression that memcpy was endianness agnostic.  I would think that the left-most bit would stay the left must bit.  However when I attempt to print the characters each word is copied backwards.
Why does this happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <array>

const unsigned int MAX_VALUE = 64ul;
typedef unsigned char DDS_Octet[MAX_VALUE];
int main()
{
    // create an array and populate it with printable 
    // characters
    DDS_Octet octet;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; ++i)
        octet[i] = (i + 33);

    // print characters before the memcpy operation
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; ++i)
    {
        if(i && !(i % 4)) std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << octet[i] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n------------------------------\n";

    // This is an equivalent copy operation
    // to what is actually being used
    std::array<unsigned int, 16> arr;
    memcpy(
        arr.data(),
        octet,
        sizeof(octet));

    // print the character contents of each
    // word left to right (MSB to LSB on little endian)
    for(auto i : arr)
        std::cout 
        << (char)(i >> 24) << "\t" 
        << (char)((i >> 16) & 0xFF) << "\t" 
        << (char)((i >> 8) & 0xFF) << "\t"
        << (char)(i & 0xFF) << "\n";
```

** output **

```
!   "   #   $   
%   &   '   (   
)   *   +   ,   
-   .   /   0   
1   2   3   4   
5   6   7   8   
9   :   ;   <   
=   >   ?   @   
A   B   C   D   
E   F   G   H   
I   J   K   L   
M   N   O   P   
Q   R   S   T   
U   V   W   X   
Y   Z   [   \   
]   ^   _   `   

------------------------------
$   #   "   !
(   '   &   %
,   +   *   )
0   /   .   -
4   3   2   1
8   7   6   5
<   ;   :   9
@   ?   >   =
D   C   B   A
H   G   F   E
L   K   J   I
P   O   N   M
T   S   R   Q
X   W   V   U
\   [   Z   Y
`   _   ^   ]
```

----Update-----
I took a look at the memcpy source code (below) which was far more simple than expected.  It actually explains everything.  It would seem that it would be correct to say that the endianness of the integer is the cause for this, but incorrect to say that memcpy does not play a role.  What I was overlooking what that data is being copied on a byte-by-byte operation.  Given that, it makes sense that the little endian integer would reverse it.

```
void *
memcpy (void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
{
  char *d = dest;
  const char *s = src;
  while (len--)
    *d++ = *s++;
  return dest;
}
```

Comment: The value 0x12345678 is stored as 4 bytes: 0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12. But 0x12345678>>24 is still 0x12. Does that help you understand?

Comment: memcopy may be but `int` is not endianness agnostic. `i` is an int

Comment: @user253751 I understand that.  when I shifted 24 bits the intent was to print the first character of the array.  I would have expected a ! as opposed to a $

Comment: It doesn’t sound like you understand what he was saying. Shifting right by 24 bits gives you the 8 most significant bits. It does not (necessarily) give you the *first* 8 bits.

Comment: your conclusion isnt sound. You should copy `char`s and look at the `char`s before and after the `memcpy`. You will see that the order didnt change. Your misunderstanding is how reinterpreting 4 chars as one `int` works.

Comment: .. in other words. You do not need a memcpy to see the same effect.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing the phrase, "endianness *agnostic*" with, "endianness *independent*"? The `memcpy` function doesn't *care* about endianness but the `unsigned int` array that you're copying into *does* care.

Comment: ... for `uchar x = 0xFF; uint i; memcpy(&i, &x, 1);` then, `x` will go to either the MS byte or LS byte of `i`, **depending on the endianness** of `uint` on the target platform.

Comment: Endianness is only an issue when you treat memory as a multi-byte object.  When you're working with byte streams (like memcpy), endianness is not an issue.  But when you load 4 bytes into a 32-bit register, endianness determines how that register will look.

Answer (score 2):

When you `memcpy` 4 `char`s into a 4-byte `unsigned int` they get stored in the same order they were in the original array.  That is, the first `char` in the input array will be stored in the lowest address byte of the `unsigned int`, the second in the second lowest address byte, and so on.

x86 is little-endian.  The lowest address byte of an `unsigned int` is the least significant byte.

The shift operators are endianess-independent though.  They work on the *logical* representation of an integer, not the physical bytes.  That means, for an `unsigned int` `i` on a little-endain platform, `i & 0xFF` gives the lowest address byte and `(i >> 24) & 0xFF` gives the highest address byte, while on a big-endian platform `i & 0xFF` gives the highest address byte and `(i >> 24) & 0xFF` gives the lowest address byte.

Taken together, these threee facts explain why your data is reversed.  `'!'` is the first `char` in your array, so when you `memcpy` that array into an array of `unsigned int` `'!'` becomes the lowest address byte of the first `unsigned int` in the destination array.  The lowest address byte is the least significant on your little-endian platform, and so that is the byte you retrieve with `i & 0xFF`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will let you understand easier. Let's say we have these data defined:

```
uint32_t val = 0x01020304;
auto *pi = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>( &val );
```

Following code will produce the same result on big-endian and little-endian platform:

```
std::cout << ( (val >> 24) & 0xFF ) << '\t'
          << ( (val >> 16) & 0xFF ) << '\t'
          << ( (val >> 8) & 0xFF ) << '\t'
          << ( (val >> 0) & 0xFF ) << '\n';
```

but this code will have different output:

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>( pi[0] ) << '\t'
          << static_cast<unsigned int>( pi[1] ) << '\t'
          << static_cast<unsigned int>( pi[2] ) << '\t'
          << static_cast<unsigned int>( pi[3] ) << '\n';
```

it has nothing to do with `memcpy()`, it is how `int`s are stored in memory and how bit shifting operation works.

Answer (score 1):

The value 0x12345678 is stored as 4 bytes: 0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12. But 0x12345678>>24 is still 0x12 because that has nothing to do with the 4 separate bytes.

If you have the 4 bytes: 0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12, and interpret them as a 4-byte little-endian integer, you get 0x12345678. If you right-shift by 24 bits, you get the 4th byte: 0x12. If you right-shift by 16 bits and mask with 0xff, you get the 3rd byte: 0x34. And so on. Because `((0x12345678 >> 16) & 0xff) == 0x34`

The memcpy has nothing to do with it.